# I wanna add 2 slideshow in one single webpages so this is the code for 1 slide show

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow

I wanna add 2 slideshow in one single webpages so this is the code for 1 slide show

```
<script>

var slideIndex = 0;
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides1");
showSlides();

function showSlides() {    
var i;    
for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none"; 
}
slideIndex++;
if (slideIndex> slides.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
setTimeout(showSlides, 3000); // Change image every 5 seconds
}

function currentSlide(no) {
var i;    
for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none"; 
}
slideIndex = no;
slides[no-1].style.display = "block";


function plusSlides(n) {
  var newslideIndex = slideIndex + n;
  if(newslideIndex < 6 && newslideIndex > 0){
 currentSlide(newslideIndex);
  }
}
</script>
```

then I wanted to add another slideshow so I add mySlides2

```
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides1", "mySlides2");
```

but it's not working .

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('.mySlides1, .mySlides2');` try this instead of `getElementsByClassName`

Comment: still not working.. myslides2 is empty

Answer (score 0):

Get your slide elements into two HTMLCollections then combine them into one array.

```
var slide1 = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides1");
var slide2 = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides1");
var slides = [];

for(var i = 0; i < slide1.length; i++){
    slides[i] = slide1[i];
}
for(var length = slide1.length, i = length; i < slide2.length+length; i++ ){
    slides[i] = slide2[i - length];
}
//showSlides();
```